# Why does my background-image become bigger?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks that cosist of parent and child blocks. For my parent block I establish `min-height: 360px;`. It will help to became my block bigger when I add some text. But even if I don't add more text it becomes bigger.

How can I solve this problem without establshing to my parent block `height: 360px;`?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.groups_line {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1565px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.line {
    width: 520px;
    min-height: 360px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.first_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/X7K9PsbD/13-2x.png);
}

.second_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/hGvxfg7H/kaboompics-com-Woman-preparing-a-lunch-on-the-kitchen-table.png);
}

.third_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/s2GXk2WD/photo-1453822858805-7c095c06011e.png);
}

.wrapper_foot {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 18px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.heading_block {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #b59f5b;
    margin: 20px 10px 15px 10px;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.data {
    opacity: 0.54;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.number {
    opacity: 0.54;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline;
}

.fa-comment {
    color: #b59f5b;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
}

.border {
    width: 465px;
    min-height: 135px;
    border: 3px solid #b59f5b;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;500;600&family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="groups_line">
            <div class="first_group line">
                <div class="first-group-line border">
                    <p class="group_line heading_block">beauty   health  life</p>
                    <p class="group_line text">FROM GRAPEFRUIT TO LEMONS TO ORANGES, CITRUS DOES YOU GOOD!</p>
                    <div class="wrapper_foot">
                        <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                        <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                            <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="second_group line">
            <div class="second-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading_block">health</p>
                <p class="group_line text">5 Tips To Supercharge Your 
Motivation</p>
                <div class="wrapper_foot">
                    <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                    <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                        <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_group line">
            <div class="third-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading_block">Beauty</p>
                <p class="group_line text">To Keep Makeup Looking Fresh Take A Powder</p>
                <div class="wrapper_foot">
                    <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                    <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                        <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fit the text space inside the block, I suggest using `min-height: fit-content`